# Can't return std::shared_ptr from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

i have a problem with returning of the shared pointer from a function. Exception is thrown on the line with the return statement from the function.

Here is the function:

```
// Icp.cpp
std::shared_ptr<ICPResult> Icp::fit() {

    // inner part of function

    // return values from inner part of fucntion
    double fitnessScore = icp.getFitnessScore();
    Eigen::Matrix4f transformation = icp.getFinalTransformation();

    return std::make_shared<ICPResult>(fitnessScore, transformation);
}
```

Relevant part of header header:

```
// Icp.h
std::shared_ptr<models::detection::ICPResult> fit();
```

Returned class:

```
// ICPResult.h
class ICPResult : public DetectionResult {
    public:
        ICPResult();
        ICPResult(const double score, const Eigen::Matrix4f transformation);

        Eigen::Matrix4f transformationIcp;
    private:
};
```

Parent class:

```
// DetectionResult.h
class DetectionResult {
    public:
        DetectionResult();
        DetectionResult(const double score);

        double score;

    private:
};
```

Exception was thrown at line 892 in "...VS17\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\memory" at the line with if statement

```
void _Decref()
    {   // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Uses) == 0)
        {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
        _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
        }
    }
```

Text of the exception:
*System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'*

I usually return shared pointer without any problems, but in this case i have no idea what is the problem. It seems to me like some problem with counting of references to the shared pointer, but i dont know how to handle it. I will be grateful for any ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please don't post text as image.

Comment: Im sorry this is my first post. Edited

Comment: It's.... weird, and it's not clear that it's the exact cause of the error. Can you reduce it to a minimal complete example (focus on minimal), so that everyone can try running it and check.

Comment: Returning shared_ptr the way you are using it should be fine. I don't see a general problem there. Maybe the Eigen::Matrix4f object creation / deletion is not correct? The Matrix you are passing calls the copy constructor (not passed as reference) and I assume you are calling another copy constructor when storing the Matrix in your member variable.

Comment: @FlorianM. It seems youre right. When i try to return shared pointer without Eigen:Matrix4f everything work properly. So there is some problem with passing of Matrix.

Comment: @user202729 I can write a minimalistic example, but as i wrote before i have problem at this specific case. It seem to be a problem with Matrix from Eigen lirbary.

Comment: Most likely your issue is with the fixed-size Eigen matrix and alignment issues: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution. With reference to @Paul B answer the problem was that every class or structure which contain Eigen data types have to handle with fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types. For more info about this problem please visit https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html

Solution for my specific problem is adding EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW macro to public part of the ICPResult.h

```
// ICPResult.h
class ICPResult : public DetectionResult {
    public:
        ICPResult();
        ICPResult(const double score, const Eigen::Matrix4f transformation);

        Eigen::Matrix4f transformationIcp;
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    private:
};
```

Many thanks